# Is it possible to add an image to a custom MGLAnnotationView in MapBox (iOS, Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapbox

Mapbox provides handy documentation on customising an annotation's image and customising an annotation's view:

https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/annotation-views/
https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/marker-image/

However it doesn't seem possible to combine these ideas and customise an annotation view's image. Basically what I am hoping to do is have an annotation of a photo (which the user picks) which also has a boarder which can be animated when tapped.

Has anyone ran into this limitation as well?

Answer (score 7):

[`MGLAnnotationView`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.5.2/Classes/MGLAnnotationView.html) inherits from `UIView`, so most any technique you might use to add an image to a view will also work here.

A simple way would be to add `UIImageView` as a subview in a custom `MGLAnnotationView` subclass:

```
class CustomImageAnnotationView: MGLAnnotationView {
    var imageView: UIImageView!

    required init(reuseIdentifier: String?, image: UIImage) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        self.addSubview(self.imageView)
        self.frame = self.imageView.frame
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
}
```

And then use that subclass in [`mapView:viewForAnnotation:`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.5.2/Protocols/MGLMapViewDelegate.html#/c:objc(pl)MGLMapViewDelegate(im)mapView:viewForAnnotation:):

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {
    guard annotation is MGLPointAnnotation else {
        return nil
    }

    let imageName = "someImageThatYouHaveAddedToYourAppBundle"

    // Use the image name as the reuse identifier for its view.
    let reuseIdentifier = imageName

    // For better performance, always try to reuse existing annotations.
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    // If there’s no reusable annotation view available, initialize a new one.
    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = CustomImageAnnotationView(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, image: UIImage(named: imageName)!)
    }

    return annotationView
}
```

Comment: Hi @friedbunny, your answer helped me, but I have few question as I'm completely new to mapbox,what if I'm already having another reusableIdentifier i.e. "annotation.coordinate.longitude" and I want to cover the whole annotation with the image, and to show different images on annotation based on some type, say category of the location annotation.

Comment: Hi, got the solution of showing different images on the annotation based on the type (say- bar, gym, shop etc.), but couldn't get rid of displaying the image on the complete annotation.

Answer (score 1):

```
func mapView( _ mapView: MGLMapView, imageFor annotation: MGLAnnotation ) -> MGLAnnotationImage? {
  var annotationImage : MGLAnnotationImage? = nil
  annotationImage = MGLAnnotationImage( image:UIImage( named: "imageyouwanttoset", reuseIdentifier: annotation.title ) )
  return annotationImage
}
```